# sends information from the input field along with uploadify

Tags: php, jquery, html, file-upload, uploadify

How can I post the value from an input field with the files I uploaded to the server whit ***UPLOADIFY***?

```
<tr>
    <th>text:</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="userInput" id="userInput" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>files:</th>
    <td><input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" /></td>
</tr>


<script type="text/javascript">
'onUploadStart' : function(){
    $('#file_upload').uploadifySettings(
            'postData', 
            {
                "userInput": $("#userInput").val()
            }
    );
},
</script>
```

This will working not yet, but how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fileInput').uploadify({
        'uploader'  : 'uploadify.swf',
        'script'    : 'upload.php',
        'cancelImg' : 'cancel.png',
        'auto'      : true,
        'folder'    : '/your_folder_to_upload',
        'onOpen' : function(){
        $('#file_upload').uploadifySettings(
            'scriptData', 
            {'userInput':$("#userInput").val()}
            );
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: And how can i post the userInput to a other page (upload.php)?

Comment: you can get the userInupt val in upload.php by doing $_POST["userInput"]